# ASP.NET, DDD, IoC, Repository Pattern - simple demo app?

Tags: asp.net, domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am fresh out of college and I've been put on a project using the technologies/techniques mentioned in the title. It's all a bit mind boggling to learn these new patterns on such a large codebase so I was wondering if there is a sample app somewhere (something ridiculously basic like a phonebook maybe?) that will demo these patterns. Thanks!

(Castle Windsor is the framework in use and then there's a custom built ORM library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked the [sharparchitecture.net Tutorial](http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/TutorialIndex.ashx). Although it is a tutorial about sharparchitecture it covers testdrivendevelopment(TDD), ASP.NET, DDD, Repository Pattern and the use of Interfaces which is the base of IoC.

Answer (score 2):

["Who can help me"](https://github.com/jongeorge1/Who-Can-Help-Me) is a nice reference web app using Sharp Architecture (ASP.NET MVC, NHibernate, Windsor, repositories). It's not a trivial app though, but in a trivial app you wouldn't see how these technologies fit together anyway.